# In WinDbg, how can one find all the places where a specific event is referenced?

Tags: debugging, windbg

For example, I have a thread which is waiting for an event:

```
THREAD ffffd40429f65700  Cid 03d4.0464  Teb: 0000006aefeb4000 Win32Thread: ffffd4042aced0e0 WAIT: (UserRequest) UserMode Alertable
            ffffd4042ada46d0  NotificationEvent
```

And I want to find out which other threads (possibly in other processes) are using the same event, be it waiting for the event or being supposed to signal the event at some moment.

I'm aware of `!trueref -v`, which gives me this:

```
0: kd> !trueref -v ffffd4042ada46d0
    Process ffffd40428c713c0 has no handles!
    Process: ffffd40429ea3780 Handle:   1a4 Entry: ffffa90fb34be690 RefCount: 32718

ffffd4042ada46d0: HandleCount: 1 PointerCount: 32720 RealPointerCount: 2
```

From what I understand, there are 2 pointers to this event somewhere (one of them I assume is from this thread itself). So how can I find where the other pointer is so that I find the other thread using (probably the one that signals) the same event?

Comment: "supposed to signal the event at some moment" - this would require looking into the future. It's not possible.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding. An event is an object. Any thread that has access to the object may signal it, i.e. every thread that shares the same address space.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I looked at the [MS sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-event-objects) and I think I understand it now. But I still don't understand what that "RealPointerCount" means and whether it's of any use for me to figure out what that event is about (i.e. when it's going to get signaled).

Comment: `RealPointerCount` considers the new way of Windows 8.1+ how these numbers ard stored internally. Compare that output to the one of `!object`. It will probably give you 32769 as `PointerCount`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I reviewed Windows Internals' section on the object manager and also found Ionescu's blog post about the changes you mentioned and now I finally get it. Thanks.